# navigating nautilus tree using arrow keys

Tags: nautilus

I use mostly command line tools, but sometimes browsing a directory tree is more easy using GUI. In PCManFM I could use the arrow keys to walk the tree and left arrow and right arrow would open a closed tree node (as did explorer on Windows XP).

Nautilus requires to use <kbd>Return</kbd> to open a directory if selected (using up and down) and I have not found a way to close using a key.

Is there a way to configure nautilus so I can do all navigation, in the left pane tree, with the arrow keys instead of using the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key together with arrow keys to navigate through Nautilus.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> closes a unfolded directory (but does not go up the tree)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> opens a folded directory (but does not enter)

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd> with the left and right arrow keys walks through the history of accessed directories, but it does not do any folding/unfolding of the tree (and is always confusing me).

Comment: Did not know and it helps, but is there a way to do without having to use shift?

Comment: Not via the preferences. I noticed the above by accident.